# How to access deployed BrowserRouter used react project after depolying into tomcat server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, servlet-container, react-dom-server

I would like to use BrowserRouter for creating multi-page react appplication where I can access different modules with different router names.
I can switch between Home and About modules with http://localhost:3000/home and http://localhost:3000/about respectively.

My main intention to create this router-based application is to deploy the build files into server from where we need to access the project.

I can access my project with http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html after deploying the files into one of my context folders(myapp).

Problem is how to switch between modules which I can do with http://localhost:3000/home.
How to access Home and About modules from deployment.(Tomcat).
PLease help me on this.

App.js :

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./About";
import Home from "./Home";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <Home />} />
        <Route path="/About" render={() => <About />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The whole purpose of using a client-side framework like React is to avoid using static HTML pages. Not sure, why are you using React if you want to deploy like the old times?

Comment: Please let me know if any way to access the deployed project with different routers.